# How to get AWS API Gateway to validate JSON Body against Model

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, jsonschema

The newly released "x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator" (in April I believe) is supposed to be able to run a JSON schema validation against the POST/PUT payload of an API.

I've tried to implement this in several different ways now but I can't make it work...
I have added the validators:

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators": {
  "ValidateBody": {
    "validateRequestParameters": false,
    "validateRequestBody": true
  },
  "ValidateHeaders": {
    "validateRequestParameters": true,
    "validateRequestBody": false
  }
```

}

For any methind I will look for specific headers so I also have the parameters in the "root" of the Swagger:

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator": "ValidateHeaders"
```

In the POST I have a `x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: ValidateBody` and then a Model with the JSON schema where several elements are `required`.

I can however POST anything as long as it is JSON... There is no validation against the JSON schema done...

What am I missing?

Comment: This is the guide I have followed: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-request-validation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working!
There is a time lag between the deploy and the actual usage of the new code even though I am not doing any caching it seems.

Went out for lunch and came back to a working solution!

```
{
  "message": "Invalid request body"
}
```

It would be nice to be able to modify the response message though...

Comment: Hi Anders, I am facing the same issue. I'm wondering if it is impossible to customize this response message?

Comment: Yes, if you check under "Gateway Responses" you'll find `Bad Request Body (400)` where you can alter the message

Comment: @Anders I asked something related in https://stackoverflow.com/q/47953570/89771, do you happen to know the solution by any chance?