# Get detailed error messages from AWS API Gateway Request Validator

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway

### Background

I have an API Gateway created using Swagger 2.0 definitions with [API Gateway extensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-gateway-responses.html).

I overrode the default API Gateway responses, for instance:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses:
  BAD_REQUEST_BODY:
    statusCode: 400
    responseTemplates:
      application/json: |
        {
          "error": {
            "code": 400,
            "stage": "$context.stage",
            "request": "$context.requestId",
            "message": "$context.error.message"
          }
        }
```

The `$context` in the above payload comes from [API Gateway variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference).

A sample resource/method in my API looks like this (always `LAMBDA_PROXY` integrations):

```
paths:
  /test:
    post:
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: Test
          required: true
          schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Test"
      responses:
        201:
          description: Created
        400:
          description: Bad Request
        401:
          description: Unauthorized
        403:
          description: Forbidden
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
      uri: >-
        arn:aws:apigateway:${region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambda}/invocations
      type: aws_proxy
      httpMethod: POST
      credentials: "${credentials}"
      passthroughBehavior: never
```

With the corresponding request payload definition:

```
definitions:
  Test:
    type: object
    title: Test
    required:
      - date
    properties:
      date:
        type: string
        pattern: "^20[0-9]{2}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"
        description: Date in YYYY-MM-DD Format
```

And the [request validator extensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-request-validator.html):

```
x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: body
x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators:
  body:
    validateRequestBody: true
    validateRequestParameters: false
```

### Problem

When I call this endpoint with a missing or invalid `date`, I always get the same response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "stage": "latest",
        "request": "6b7a64f5-e7f0-11e7-845b-f53ceb4cb049",
        "message": "Invalid request body"
    }
}
```

However, when I test it through the API Gateway console without the `date` property:

```
Request body does not match model schema for content type application/json: [
  object has missing required properties (["date"])
]
```

And with an invalid `date`:

```
Request body does not match model schema for content type application/json: [
  ECMA 262 regex "^20[0-9]{2}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$" does not match input string "2017/12/25"
]
```

### Question

How can I access the detailed error message so that I can enrich my error response with a more descriptive message than `Invalid request body`? I suspect that this must be possible, perhaps using [`x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-gateway-responses.html) mapping, but so far I haven't been able to do it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

UPDATE:

This is now possible with gateway responses. Setup a [`BAD_REQUEST_BODY`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/supported-gateway-response-types.html) gateway response  with the below template:

```json
{"message": "$context.error.validationErrorString"}
```

---

(Developer on API Gateway)

Unfortunately, this is not supported right now. We are actively working on fixing this issue, but I can't give you any specific timelines by when this  could be supported.

Comment: Is CORS on validation error related to your response? https://stackoverflow.com/q/48710640/1480391

Comment: How can this be achieved using the serverless framework?

Comment: @ShwetaJ I don't know about serverless but in aws sam you can use `Gateway Responses`  [property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-api-gatewayresponses) as follows:  
`{
  "GatewayResponses": {
    "DEFAULT_4xx": {
      "ResponseParameters": {
        "Headers": {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
        }
      },
      "ResponseTemplates": {
        "application/json": "{\"message\": \"$context.error.validationErrorString\"}"
      }
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 6):

Since API Gateway developer had answered the question, I still want to add some tips for you, maybe it is helpful and that can be an accepted answer!

For your question, in fact you need to active the cloudwatch logs for api gateway, with that, you can get more logs than you have before.

Let me know if it included the details for `Request Validator`

This [aws document - How do I enable Amazon CloudWatch Logs for APIs I created in the Amazon API Gateway?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/) gives the steps on how to enable it.

But I prefer to go with this document [API Gateway and Lambda Logs](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/api-gateway-and-lambda-logs.html), which give the screenshots to follow up easily.

In your api gateway, you should see this is enabled. 
[image]

Access the API gateway several times, go through the log group which is named as:

```
API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_{rest-api-id}/{stage_name}
```

[image]

Which has more details than the information you have as `Invalid request body` and others, such as `{"message": "Internal server error"}`. It is very useful feature, that save me a lot time troubleshooting serverless and api gateway issues.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, within the Gateway Responses section, go to:

```
Bad Request Body [400]

Change the value of the body mapping template to: 

{"message":$context.error.validationErrorString}
```

Ex Output:

```
{
"message": "[instance value (\"us\") not found in enum (possible values: [\"usd\",\"eur\",\"gbp\",\"jpy\",\"aud\",\"chf\",\"cad\",\"nzd\"])]"
}
```

Comment: The question is about Swagger, not Amazon Console. Please update your answer because it is only the half of it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your question but rather an alternative workaround that we've used in our apps that serves the same purpose (request validation).

Our serverless API started by defining all our endpoints in API Gateway (complete with Swagger documentation). Over time, we've added a lot more endpoints (around 60+ endpoints consisting of legacy REST endpoints, public REST endpoints, and private graphQL endpoints).

Managing this number of endpoints through API Gateway proved to be very tedious, and deploy time took very long (we we're using `serverless`).

Eventually, we decided to reduce it into three "monolith" serverless applications. Two REST endpoints and one GraphQL endpoint.

So basically, we handled the routing inside our Lambda handlers (and routing is not necessary for GraphQL).

For request validation, it comes for free with GraphQL (another reason to love GraphQL). As for our REST handler, we use JSON schemas and any validation error, we can easily return back to the client together with an HTTP 400 error message.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this in Cloudformation or SAM add this bit:

```
SomeAPI:
  Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Api'
  Properties:
    GatewayResponses:
      BAD_REQUEST_BODY:
        ResponseTemplates:
          "application/json": '{ "message": "$context.error.validationErrorString"}'
```