# Enable CORS when using AWS API Gateway Request Validator

Tags: cors, aws-api-gateway, request-validation

I setup AWS API Gateway with CORS successfully, when a request is valid I have a 200 status code and also CORS headers, that's nice.

But when AWS API Gateway Request Validator detects an invalid input, I have the status code is 400 but CORS headers are not sent...

That's really unfortunate, because the client sees a CORS errors instead of a real 400 error (for exemple with `fetch` the client is not able to distinguish 400 errors because of CORS errors).

This question may be related to [Get detailed error messages from AWS API Gateway Request Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47953570/1480391)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I came to this answer through a discussion about using serverless to deploy CORS services and dealing with errors thrown from API Gateway: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3896#issuecomment-333910525

Basically, you need to go to API Gateway, select your API, then select Gateway Responses.  You can then add headers for any `4XX` or `5XX` response.

[image: API Gateway, Gateway Responses]

This will allow 400 errors thrown from API Gateway to work with CORS, since you're adding the needed headers here.

Comment: Beautiful, this is exactly what I was looking for. Just a note to others, this took a few minutes to take effect. You can test that it is responding as you expect by initially modifying the error JSON response with a custom message as well.