# Detailed validation error message for AWS API Gateway Websocket API

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, jsonschema

AWS API Gateway WebSocket APIs [support request validation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/websocket-api-request-validation.html) using models defined using JSON Schema.

When a request is sent by the client that doesn’t conform to the schema, API Gateway will send a message back which says `”Invalid request body”`.

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953570/get-detailed-error-messages-from-aws-api-gateway-request-validator), but for websocket APIs, is there a way to return a better error message than “Invalid request body”?

I notice that `$context.error.validationErrorString` is in the [mapping template reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-mapping-template-reference.html), but I can’t see anything equivalent to rest API’s “[gateway responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/supported-gateway-response-types.html)” like `BAD_REQUEST_BODY`.